# Mongoose varias bases de datos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, schema

tengo un archivo llamado `database.js` con este codigo:

```javascript
module.exports = {
    conn: (dbname, model, schema) => {
        const conn = mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb+srv://user:password@main.aphla.mongodb.net/${dbname}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
            .then((db) => {
                console.log('DB \'' + dbname + '\' connected');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        conn.model(model, schema);
    }
}
```

que cuando en otro archivo, por ejemplo `file.js` lo importo y ejecuto su función conn:

```javascript
const db = require('./database');
db.conn('nombreDB', 'nombreCollection', schema);
```

pero cuando ejecuto el codigo dice:

```
conn.model(model, schema);
     ^

TypeError: conn.model is not a function
```

creo que el error ocurre porque mongoose necesita tiempo para conectarse a la base de datos pero según su web asi funciona

Comment: ¿Y porqué usas el mismo nombre de función `conn` que la variable interna de la misma `const conn = ...`? Cuando llamas a `conn.model(model, schema);` ¿a cuál se estará refiriendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manejar multiples conexiones a bases de datos (multitenant) puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente

```js
// File => mongoose.js 
const mongoose = require( 'mongoose' )
const db = mongoose.createConnection(
    `${ process.env.MONGO_URI }`,
    db_options
)
db.on( 'open', () => console.log( 'Mongoose successfully connected...' ) )
db.on( 'error', err => console.log( 'Mongoose connection error', err) )
module.exports.database = db
```

Luego al importarlo en cualquier otro archivo donde necesites cambiar la conexión

```js
const { database } = require( 'path/to/mongooseFile' )
const schemaModel = require('path/to/schemaFile')
// Le indicas que Base de datos usar
const conn1 = database.useDb( 'Base1', { useCache: true } )

// Y Finalmente para los modelos
const Model1 = conn1.model('Model',schemaModel, 'Model')
```

Cabe destacar que para que esta implementación funcione debes exportar el esquema luego de definirlo.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono pero tuve que cambiar:
`module.exports.database = db`
por
```
module.exports.db = () => {
    return database;
};
```